# Change legend title and legend values in geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

For a sample dataframe:

```
     df <- tibble(
      x = c(1:6, 1:6),
      y = c(1, 5, 6, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 2, 2),
      f = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6)) 
    )
```

I am plotting line graphs of 'f' with their corresponding x and y coordinates.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group = f))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = f, col = f))
p
```

I am however trying to change the legend title from 'f' to "animal" and "a" to "cat" and "b" to dog. When I try to run:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group = f))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype = f, col = f))+
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Animal", labels = c("cat", "dog"))
p
```

I get the error:
Error in `f()`:

```
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 2 needed but only 0 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Can someone please explain why when I am inputting two labels (cat/dog), ggplot2 doesn't recognise them as such.

Comment: I specifically want to not use color in aes (which is what I should have made clear in the question). @TarJae helped me greatly but as still wish to pursue using linetype alone, and create legend labels/values from these.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group = f, color=f))+
  geom_line(linetype = 2)+
  labs(color = "Animal")+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("cat", "dog"), values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Are you looking for such a solution:

We have to change the code a little.
Rule of thumb and what helps is to remember each `aes` will show a legend.
And if the aes is `color` we can change them as appropriate:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group = f, color=f))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(color = "Animal")+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("cat", "dog"), values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @TarJae, I was staring at that for ages and couldn't see the solution!

Comment: Sorry, one more question @TarJae: if I wanted to keep the linetype (for dashes etc) and not colour why does the equivalent scale_linetype_manual not work?

Comment: geom_line(linetype = 2) is dashed line. Please see my update. In principle a lot of things are possible. It depends on what we want.